# How do I work with Multiple Recordsets in C++ ODBC

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

I am trying to streamline a complex process of storing information in multiple tables and them linking them to a central table.  The linking occurs using IDENTITY values generated in each table to provide the unique linking.  I know I can use a combination of SET NOCOUNT ON and SELECT @@identity to get each identity, but that still requires me to call a separate SQLExecute() for each table.  I have read dozens of articles saying ADO can handle multiple recordsets using an ODBC driver, so the question is how do I do it without ADO?

I have already encapsulated all of the standard ODBC stuff for similar behavior to ADO.  I basically just need to know what ODBC API calls will allow me to recreate ADO's NextRecorset().

I am working on a combination of MS SQL 7 and MS SQL 2005, using either the SQL Server ODBC, or SQL Native Client Drivers as appropriate.

End Goal:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO TableA (data) VALUES ('a');
SELECT @@identity AS  NewID;
INSERT INTO TableB (data) VALUES ('b');
SELECT @@identity AS  NewID;
INSERT INTO TableC (data) VALUES ('c');
SELECT @@identity AS  NewID;
...
RS = DB.OpenRecordset()
RS.MoveFirst()
A_ID = RS.GetValue("id")
RS.NextRecordset()
RS.MoveFirst()
B_ID = RS.GetValue("id")
RS.NextRecordset()
RS.MoveFirst()
C_ID = RS.GetValue("id")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `SQLMoreResults()` call as the analog to the `NextRecordSet()` function.

However you probably don't need that if you are willing to make your executes consist of `INSERT ...; SELECT @@IDENTITY` Since the only result returned from this statement is the identity, you don't need to bother with the `SQLMoreResults()`.